Fourth Moment of Stochastic Gradient Approximation

Given the batch size $p\in\mathbb N$ and $N$ vectors $x_1,\cdots,x_N\in\mathbb R^d$ with $|x_i|\le 1$, please prove that there exists a constant $C$ independent of $d,N,p$ such that
$$
\mathbb E\Bigg[\bigg|\frac1p\sum_{i\in S} x_i - \frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N x_i\bigg|^4\Bigg] \le C\bigg(\frac1p-\frac1N\bigg)^2,
$$
where $S$ is a random subset of $\{1,\cdots,N\}$ of size $p$ and the expectation is taken with respect to all possible $S$.

This is a problem from my study of the error analysis of the stochastic gradient descent (SGD) methods, where the partial mean $p^{-1}\sum_{i\in S} x_i$ can be viewed as a mini-batch approximation to the full mean $N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i$. If we only consider the second moments, then it is easy to show
$$
\mathbb E\Bigg[\bigg|\frac1p\sum_{i\in S} x_i - \frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N x_i\bigg|^2\Bigg] \le C\bigg(\frac1p-\frac1N\bigg),
$$
by directly expanding the expectation in the LHS. However, the fourth moment requires much more calculation and the proof can be extremely difficult. I have tried to prove this result when $d=1$ by explicitly computing the expectation in the LHS, which involves terms like $\sum x_i^2 x_j x_k$. For a general $d$, is it possible to prove this result in a rather clean and elegant way?

For the $d=1$ case, I post my proof below. First we introduce the constants
$$
A_4 = \frac1N \sum_{(i)} x_i^4,~~~~
A_{31} = \frac1{N(N-1)} \sum_{(ij)} x_i^3 x_j,~~~~
A_{22} = \frac1{N(N-1)} \sum_{(ij)} x_i^2 x_j^2,
$$
$$
A_{211} = \frac1{N(N-1)(N-2)} \sum_{(ijk)} x_i^2 x_j x_k,~~~~
A_{1111} = \frac1{N(N-1)(N-2)(N-3)} \sum_{(ijkl)} x_ix_jx_k x_l,
$$
where the subscript $(ijk)$ means the summation is computed with respect to all $(i,j,k)$ tuples with distinct $i,j,k$. As a consequence, $A_4,A_{31},A_{22},A_{211},A_{1111}$ can be viewed as the average of the product terms, and they are all in the range $[-1,1]$.
Next, by direct but tedious calculation, we find that the desired fourth moment is equal to
$$
\mathbb E\Bigg[\bigg|\frac1p\sum_{i\in S} x_i - \frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N x_i\bigg|^4\Bigg] = C_4 A_4 + C_{31} A_{31} + C_{22} A_{22} + C_{211} A_{211} + C_{1111} A_{1111},
$$
where the coefficients are given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
C_4 & = \frac{(N-p)(N^2-3Np+3p^2)}{N^3p^3}, \\
C_{31} & = -\frac{4(N-p)(N^2-3Np+3p^2)}{N^3p^3} , \\
C_{22} & = \frac{3(N-p)(N^2p - Np^2 -N^2+3Np-3p^2)}{N^3p^3},  \\
C_{211} & = - \frac{6(N-p)(N^2p-Np^2-2N^2+6Np-6p^2)}{N^3p^3}, \\
C_{1111} & = \frac{3(N-p)(N^2p-Np^2-2N^2+6Np-6p^2)}{N^3p^3}.
\end{aligned}
$$
The correctness of this equality has been numerically verified using MATLAB. These coefficients satisfy
$$
|C_4| \le \frac{5(N-p)^2}{N^2p^2},~~~~
|C_{31}| \le \frac{20(N-p)^2}{N^2p^2},~~~~
|C_{22}| \le \frac{18(N-p)^2}{N^2p^2},
$$
$$
|C_{211}| \le \frac{66(N-p)^2}{N^2p^2},~~~~
|C_{1111}| \le \frac{33(N-p)^2}{N^2p^2},
$$
hence we conclude the inequality
$$
\mathbb E\Bigg[\bigg|\frac1p\sum_{i\in S} x_i - \frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N x_i\bigg|^4\Bigg] \le \frac{142(N-p)^2}{N^2p^2},
$$
and the constant $C$ can be chosen as 142.

In the $d>1$ case, a brief idea of the proof is stated below. We can similarly introduce the constants
\begin{equation*}
 A_{11,11} = \frac1N \sum_{(i)} |x_i|^4,~~
 A_{11,12} = \frac1{N(N-1)} \sum_{(ij)} |x_i|^2 (x_i\cdot x_j),
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 A_{11,22} = \frac1{N(N-1)} \sum_{(ij)} |x_i|^2 |x_j|^2,~~
 A_{12,12} = \frac1{N(N-1)} \sum_{(ij)} (x_i\cdot x_j)^2,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 A_{12,13} = \frac1{N(N-1)(N-2)} \sum_{(ijk)} (x_i\cdot x_j) (x_i\cdot x_k),~~
 A_{11,23} = \frac1{N(N-1)(N-2)} \sum_{(ijk)} |x_i|^2 (x_j\cdot x_k),
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 A_{12,34} = \frac1{N(N-1)(N-2)(N-3)} \sum_{(ijkl)}
 (x_i\cdot x_j) (x_k\cdot x_l).
\end{equation*}
Theoretically, the fourth moment is a linear combination of the constants $A_{11,11},\cdots,A_{12,34}$ above. If it can proved that the corresponding coefficients are all no larger than $\frac{(N-p)^2}{N^2p^2}$ (up to a constant), then the proof is complete.
